# Issue about using "and"word

Tags: grammar

My question is if subject for "say" is "him" or "we" ?

1. We want him to come and to say something interesting about the goverment.
2. We want him to come and say something interesting about the goverment.

Comment: The subject is *him!* Even the *context* supports it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject is **him** for both *say and come*. Also, you don't have to repeat *to inf.* for two verbs linked by a coordinator *and*

*We want him to come and say something interesting about the government* is correct